# Do i need to validate the audience/issuer with OIDC JWT Validation in .NetCore?

Tags: openid-connect, asp.net-core-6.0

I have implemented a .Net Core 6 Web API with a Vue front end that uses Azure AD for OIDC to login to my application with JWT. The front end gets the id token from the OIDC flow but unless i register the Microsoft tenant in the valid audiences and issuers then the token will not be authenticated with the authorize attribute in the .NetCore backend. Trouble is that clients can be onboarded with our application which would then require their users to login with their Microsoft accounts - so I would need to add this to the config each time ie.

```
..
ValidAudiences = new string[] { "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111" },
ValidIssuers = new string[] { "https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111/v2.0"
..
```

I know I can turn off this validation in .NetCore (like below) this shouldn't be done right?

```
..
ValidateAudience = false,
ValidateIssuer = false
..
```

I could potentially use the workaround using IssuerValidator & AudienceValidator to validate dynamically since the audience/issuer list won't be static (set by which clients are onboarded) and cannot be set in config. Is this permitted?